# Digital Twin Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk, forge

I´m trying to connect my 3D Model with real data sensors  using Autodesk Forge, but I have a question:

Can I connect directly to the database or I must publish an API from my database with sensor data to consume it on the application?

How can I connect the data with the model?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look a this extension : [Forge DataVisualization Extension](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/developers_guide/introduction/overview/)

You will find some tutorials on how to use the visualisation components and how to connect your own sensors data.